# YouTube Data API v3 returns very few search results

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API v3 to search YouTube and parse results. Even if it says 4241 results on the response:

```
resp["pageInfo"]
{'totalResults': 4241, 'resultsPerPage': 50}
```

I only get a few videos (49 on this case).

Below is my code for getting all videos from the search API:

```
def search_youtube(keyword):
    base_video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
    base_search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?'
    # See full sample for function
    first_url = base_search_url+'key={}&q={}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50'.format(API_KEY, keyword)
video_links = []
    url = first_url

    while True:
        print(len(video_links))
        inp = requests.get(url)
        resp = json.loads(inp.text)

        for i in resp['items']:
            if i['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":
                    video_links.append(base_video_url + i['id']['videoId'])
        try:
            next_page_token = resp['nextPageToken']
            url = first_url + '&pageToken={}'.format(next_page_token)
        except:
            break
    return video_links

all_videos = search_youtube("ural altay")
```

I am never able to collect all videos from this. What can be the cause?

Comment: I think the limit is `50` per page. You can make use of `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` and implement pagination. But make sure, those to are available on every subsequent request to fetch the records.

Comment: did you check my question? I am already paginating with nextPageToken.

Comment: I'm missed it, my bad. Although the max results per page you can get is `50`.

Comment: It looks like a YouTube Data API v3 backend bug. You may be interested in reporting your issue through [Google issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/).